# Open device settings with Ionic Capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

I’m trying to find a way to open the settings/preferences app with capacitor but I’m unsuccessful.

`App.canOpenUrl({ url: 'com.apple.Preferences' })` is failing with error message `-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "com.apple.Preferences" - error: "Invalid input URL"`

I’m not sure if I’m doing it wrong or if it’s even possible with capacitor to open native app…?

[this article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/opening-another-app-from-your-ionic-5-app-becf8c098d0e) shows how to open the facebook app, but nothing about native app

Answer (score 6):

There's now a capacitor plugin for this, [capacitor native settings](https://github.com/RaphaelWoude/capacitor-native-settings).

It's similar to the cordova plugin but you have to call the correct function for each platform (iOS or Android) instead of using a single function for both.

Answer (score 2):

for someone with the same problem
Install:
[cordova-open-native-settings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-open-native-settings)

```
$ npm install cordova-open-native-settings
$ npm install @ionic-native/open-native-settings
$ ionic cap sync
```

`app.module.ts`

```js
// ...
import { OpenNativeSettings } from '@ionic-native/open-native-settings/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    // ...
    OpenNativeSettings,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`whatever.page.ts`

```js
// ...
import { OpenNativeSettings } from '@ionic-native/open-native-settings/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-whatever',
  templateUrl: './whatever.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./whatever.page.scss'],
})
export class PopoverComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    // ...
    private nativeSettings: OpenNativeSettings
  ) { }

  phoneSettings() {
    this.nativeSettings
      .open('settings')
      .then( res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch( err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }
}
```